# START IONIC APRESENTA ERRO

Tags: ionic

Boa Tarde galera, abaixo segue imagens das configurações do meu sistema Linux mint e segue também imagem do erro que estar dando quando tento iniciar o ionic , alguém saberia dizer qual erro é este?

[image: CONFIGURAÇÃO]

[image: CONFIGURAÇÃO]

[image: INICIO]

[image: CONTINUACAO]

[image: CONTINUACAO]

[image: FINALIZACAO]

Comment: Clone este repositorio fora (/var/www/html), pois pode ser que esteja havendo algum conflito entre eles. Teste /home/{seuUsuario}/Desktop/ionic/{seuProjeto}.

Comment: Hugo, não é necessário utilizar o Ionic dentro do Repositorio do Apache /var/www/html/. Crie um diretorio por exemplo na sua /home/{seuUsuario/Desktop/Ionic/. Pois dentro do /var/www/html/ ele esta pedindo permissões do Root para executar o comando.

Comment: Boa noite, já fiz isto e da o mesmo erro.

Answer (score 0):

Crie um novo projeto desta forma para entender o que esta acontecendo ?

```
cd ~
ionic start meuApp tabs
```

Após instalação execute

```
ionic serve -l
```